# Combining two data sets and plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, approximation

I am doing experiments with different operational amplifier circuits and I need to plot my measured results onto a graph. I have two data sets:

```
freq1 = [.1 .2 .5 .7 1 3 4 6 10 20 35 45 60 75 90 100]; %kHz
Vo1 = [1.2 1.6 1.2 2 2 2.4 14.8 20.4 26.4 30.4 53.6 68.8 90 114 140 152]; %mV
V1 = 19.6;
Acm = Vo1/(1000*V1);
```

And:

```
freq2 = [.1 .5 1 30 60 70 85 100]; %kHz
Vo1 = [3.96 3.96 3.96 3.84 3.86 3.88 3.88 3.88]; %V
V1 = .96;
Ad = Vo1/(2*V1);
```

(I would show my plots but apparently I need more reps for that)

I need to plot the equation, `CMRR` vs freq:

```
CMRR = 20*log10(abs(Ad/Acm));
```

The size of `Ad` and `Acm` are different and the frequency points do not match up, but the boundaries of both of these is the same, 100Hz to 100kHz (x-axis).  On the line of `CMRR`, Matlab says that `Ad` and `Acm` matrix dimensions do not agree.

How I think I would solve this is using freq1 as the x-axis for `CMRR` and then taking approximated points from `Ad` according to the value on `freq1`. 
Or I could do function approximations of `Ad` and `Acm` and then do the divide operator on those.

I do not know how I would code up this two ideas. Any other ideas would helpful, especially simpler ones.

Comment: If you use the / operator, then Matlab assumes you want to divide Matrixes by one another. You should use ./ for dividing the vectors Ad and Acm element by element. But you won't get around interpolating one of the vectors to the frequency points of the other vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `union` to get a uniform frequency axis and then use `interp1` to interpolate the data points.  We need to heed Martin's advice and use the `./` operator for element by element operations.  Here's an example:

```
Acm = Vo1./(1000*V1);
Ad = Vo1./(2*V1);
freq = union(freq1,freq2)
Acmi = interp1(freq1,Acm,freq);
Adi = interp1(freq2,Ad,freq);
% test the goodness of the interpolation
figure; plot( freq1, Acm, freq, Acmi );
legend('origial A_{cm}', 'interolated A_{cm}','Location','NorthWest');
figure; plot( freq2, Ad, freq, Adi );
legend('origial A_{d}', 'interolated A_{d}');
```

Then plot the output:

```
CMRR = 20*log10(abs(Adi./Acmi));
plot( freq, CMRR )
title('Common Mode Rejection Ratio')
xlabel('Frequency(Hz)')
ylabel('CMMR (dB)')
```

Here's my final plot:

[image: CMMR]

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is a lot easier of what I was thinking of.